# angular reactiveform property binding

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In Angular ReactiveForm examples, I saw the following code snippet:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myGroup">
   Name: <input type="text" formControlName="name">
   Location: <input type="text" formControlName="location">
</form>
```

Where myGroup is defined as:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       name: new FormControl('Todd Motto'),
       location: new FormControl('England, UK')
   });
}
```

For the property binding [formGroup]="myGroup", the data flows from the model (myGroup) to the view. So when the user change the input, how is the change reflected back in the model?

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(this.myGroup.value);
```

returns an object with "input name properties" and model values, besides there is `onValueChange` observable. So you can subscribe to it.

Comment: My question was who changes myGroup? In the  property binding [formGroup]="myGroup", the changes "flow" from myGroup to fromGroup, is not it?